pass arguments to jq when inserting key not interpolated
When I run
jq --arg md "blablabla" '. +={'content': "$md"}' blog.json

in blog.json
{
"foo": "bar"
}

I get
{
  "foo": "bar",
  "content": "$md"
}

The desired output would be:
{
  "foo": "bar",
  "content": "blablabla"
}


Try this jq --arg md "blablabla" '. + {content: $md}'

Don't put the variable in quotes if you want it to be evaluated.

BTW, the quotes around content are not correct. They're matching the quotes that are used to delimit the whole jq argument.

Note that in this case your filter could be further simplified to .content = $md.

The use of " around $md is causing JQ to interpret your input as a string literal instead of expanding the variables
Access the variable directly without quotes
jq --arg md "blablabla" '. + {"content": $md}' blog.json
output
{
  "foo": "bar",
  "content": "blablabla"
}

